# magento2 Only single product in cart

Tags: magento2, addtocart, shopping-cart

I want to do following in Magento 2

- Only one product in an entire cart
- If the cart is not empty and I add a product to the cart then product in the cart will remove and newly added replace it(a concept like swiggy)

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/207284/set-only-last-added-product-in-the-quote) will help you out.

Try following way:

> app/code/SR/Stackexchange/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart">
        <plugin name="SR_Stackexchange::add_to_cart" type="SR\Stackexchange\Plugin\Checkout\Model\Cart" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/SR/Stackexchange/Plugin/Checkout/Model/Cart.php

```
namespace SR\Stackexchange\Plugin\Checkout\Model;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;

class Cart
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
     */
    protected $checkoutSession;

    /**
     * Cart constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
    ) {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $subject
     * @param \Closure $proceed
     * @param $productInfo
     * @param null $requestInfo
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function aroundAddProduct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $productInfo,
        $requestInfo = null
    ) {

        if ($productInfo instanceof Product) {
            $productId = $productInfo->getId();
        } elseif (is_int($productInfo) || is_string($productInfo)) {
            $productId = $productInfo;
        } else {
            return $proceed($productInfo, $requestInfo);
        }

        $isSameProduct = 0;
        $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
        $items = $quote->getAllItems();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            if($productId == $item->getProductId()) {
                $isSameProduct = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if($isSameProduct) {
            return $proceed($productInfo, $requestInfo);
        }

        $quote->removeAllItems()->save();
        return $proceed($productInfo, $requestInfo);
    }
}
```

Now you need to modify when merging quote after login:

> app/code/SR/Stackexchange/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_quote_merge_before">
        <observer name="SR_Stackexchange_sales_quote_merge_before" instance="SR\Stackexchange\Observer\SalesQuoteMergeBefore"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

> app/code/SR/Stackexchange/Observer/SalesQuoteMergeBefore.php

```
namespace SR\Stackexchange\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SalesQuoteMergeBefore implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * Avoid shopping carts merging on customer login
     *
     * @param EventObserver $observer
     */
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        if ($observer->getSource()->hasItems()) {
            $currentQuote = $observer->getSource();
            $productId = 0;
            foreach ($currentQuote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
                $productId = $item->getProductId();
            }

            if (is_object($observer->getQuote()) && $observer->getQuote()->getId()) {
                $oldQuote = $observer->getQuote();
                $hasSameProduct = 0;
                foreach ($oldQuote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
                    if($productId == $item->getProductId()) {
                        $hasSameProduct = 1;
                    }
                }
                if($hasSameProduct == 0) {
                    $observer->getQuote()->removeAllItems();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Clear cache.

NB: **You can change 'SR/Stackexchange' your own module name**

Let me know if it doesn't work or if you have query.

Comment: when this event is call @Aditya Shah

Comment: The answer you provided is for Magento 1 and the question was asked for Magento 2.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove all the cart items and then add the new product to the cart.

Create a form

```
<form
    id="addsingleproduct"
    name="add_single_product"
    action="<?php $block->getUrl('module/product/addsingle') ?>">
    <!-- add your product id in the value -->
    <input type="hidden" name="product" value="10">
    <input type="hidden" name="qty" value="1">
    <input type="submit" value="Add to cart">
</form>
```

Create a controller to remove and add cart item.

```
<?php

namespace Venodr\Module\Controller\Product;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Addsingle extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    private $checkoutSession;

    private $cart;

    private $productModel;

    private $formKey;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $productModel,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey
    ) {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->productModel = $productModel;
        $this->formKey = $formKey;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        try {
            if ($this->checkoutSession->getQuote()) {
                $allItems = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
                foreach ($allItems as $item) {
                    $itemId = $item->getItemId();
                    $this->cart->removeItem($itemId)->save();
                }
            }

            $post_data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
            $product_id = $post_data['product'];
            $qty = $post_data['qty'];

            $_product = $this->productModel->load($product_id);

            $finalPriceAmt = $_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getValue();

            $params = array(
                'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
                'product' => $product_id,
                'qty' => $qty,
                'price' => $finalPriceAmt
            );

            $this->cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
            $this->cart->save();

            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
                __('Your product has been added to cart succesfully.')
            );
            $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
            return $resultRedirect;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(
                __('Something went wrong. Please try again later.')
            );
            $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
            return $resultRedirect;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `before plugin` for `public function addProduct($productInfo, $requestInfo = null)` for `class Cart` under the `namespace Magento\Checkout\Model;`

You can go through https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html to know about plugins.

In your `plugin` you can check if the cart is empty or not, for this you can use `public function getItemsCount()` of `\Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart`

If the cart is empty you can continue and if there is something in the cart then you can use `public function truncate()` of `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart` to empty the cart and then continue.

Answer (score 0):

Finally Got the simple solution

event.xml (Tatva\Cart\etc\frontend)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add">
    <observer name="tatva_cart" instance="Tatva\Cart\Observer\beforeAddToCart" />
</event>
```

beforeAddToCart.php (Tatva\Cart\Observer)

```
<?php
namespace Tatva\Cart\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class beforeAddToCart implements ObserverInterface
{

protected $_cart;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart
) 
{
    $this->_cart = $cart;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $this->_cart->truncate();
}
}
```